# I can't connect to oracle database from the internet. Only locally

Tags: database, oracle, router, tcp

the subject speaks what I have.
Machine which has oracle database instance installed is located in the internal network and has access to the internet via router device.
I set up the port mapping (1521->1521) on the router to this machine. But
when I try to connect with sqldeveloper on the host machine with oracle database then the connection is ok. But when I tried make the connection on the remote machine it sees that port (1521) is closed.
Further, I show you my status of TNS.

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 19-JAN-2017 04:29:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=onoffline.ru)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                19-JAN-2017 04:21:23
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 8 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File       C:\app\Igor\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Igor\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-LHFQ4BV\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)    (PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-LHFQ4BV)    (PORT=5500))(Security=    (my_wallet_directory=C:\APP\IGOR\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))    (Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdborcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I noticed that I close port forwarding then telnet waits too long and aborts. But When I open port forwarding for 1521 port that connection is refused immediately.

Comment: Port forwarding doesn't matter if the server isn't listening from anything other than 127.0.0.1

Comment: yes,  but port forwarding for example 80 port is working ok!

Comment: Your web server is completely separate from the database, so I don't get your point

Comment: Besides, it's a security flaw to expose your database to the Internet. Use a REST API on the web server to query the database correctly

Comment: Yes, I know that it is a security flaw, but now I want to develop application and use only one database server for developer machine and testing machine.  I don't know why it is not working, i tried many solutions. HTTP server also installed on the host machine and 80 port forwarding works on it.

Comment: Like I said HTTP is not the problem, and because that works means nothing for the database, which, by default (for good reason) is bound to only listen on 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0

Comment: Besides, you can still use the same database behind your web API

Comment: I see, and may be now I find the solution that allows me listen external connections. I think so.

Comment: share output of `netstat -ano` (assuming windows)

Comment: Yeah! You helped me. I looked at this output and noticed that my computer listened 127.0.0.1:1521, and then changed this parameters in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora to local IP address like 192.168.1.65:1521 and it works I  connected to database via internet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by editing listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.
I replaced local IP address 127.0.0.1 to something like 192.168.1.65 and It вegan to work.